# converting column types in Julia by looping over vector of columns

Tags: type-conversion, julia

after quite a few attempts i can't seem to access the columns of the dataframe pictured below (partially) for type conversion. They are all strings upon import through CSV.read, and i need them to be Numbers.

THX in advance for your time!

[image: Showing the dataframe with the first few columns to be converted (please note the Series Code column is safely not one of the columns]

I;ve tried (1)

```
col_years = contains.(names(df),"YR")
transform!(df, names(df)[col_years] .=> ByRow(x->parse(Number, x)), renamecols = false)
```

with no success as well as (2)

```
for c in names(df)[col_years]
    df[!, c] = convert.(Number, df[!, c])
end
```

Error message for (1)

```
MethodError: no method matching parse(::Type{Number}, ::String31)
Closest candidates are:
  parse(::Type{T}, ::AbstractString; base) where T<:Integer at parse.jl:240
  parse(::Type{T}, ::AbstractString; kwargs...) where T<:Real at parse.jl:379
  parse(::Type{P}, ::AbstractString; kwargs...) where P<:FilePathsBase.AbstractPath at ~/.julia/packages/FilePathsBase/9kSEl/src/path.jl:77
```

When i try using the closest candidates it still fails but when substituting Int for Number above, i get

```
ArgumentError: invalid base 10 digit '.' in "80.0511140452116"
```

(Error message for (2) is highly similar)

A df similar to the one im working with (plz NOTE Mr. Kaminski's answer works for it, apparently b/c julia likes 'String' but not 'String31' for Float64 conversions?)

```
f = DataFrame(Series  = ["SP.POP.DPND"],
                  YR1960 = ["80.0511140452116"],
                  YR1961 = ["80.2223403638055"],
                  YR1962 = ["80.4019428356728"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the values as `Float64`:

```
julia> parse(Float64, "12.3")
12.3
```

However, if `CSV.read` did not parse them as `Float64` automatically it means that some values in your data frame are invalid and cannot be parsed as numbers. In such case you can either:

1. find them and fix them (I would recommend this option),
2. or ignore them by using `tryparse`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. It proved correct with a Dataframe ive populated by hand to mirror the one from the CSV file (which the edited post above now has). But in the case of the actual data from the CSV it turns out the columns are auto rendered as "String31". In turn when trying your suggestion, the error now reads: ERROR: ArgumentError: cannot parse String31("..") as Float64

Comment: thanks, i didnt read your answer carefully enough. Finding and fixing so called 'missing' values was the key. In other environments this has only thrown warnings. The ? after String31 was not something that meant anything to me. This is veritably day 1 for me with julia.  thanks again

Comment: The `?` sign after column type name is exactly meant to signal to the user that data might contain `missing` values. In this way there is a clar visual signal of such a situation. You can also run `describe(df)` to see, in particular, how many missing values per column you have.

Comment: duly noted yesterday, but describe is something new to try. thanks again.